# Javascript error myfuntion.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

This didn't happen until I have added jQuery.

```
function mfunc() {}
mfunc.prototype.create = function(value) { 
alert("hi");
}
```

**Script before the closing body tag:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var mfunc = new mfunc();
    alert("hi");
    alert(mfunc.create("hello"));

 });
```

**I get the following error in firebug:**

> mfunc.create is not a function

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing your prototype function! Your original function is called `mfunc`, but then you are using that same variable name to refer to a new instance. Use a different variable name:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mobj = new mfunc();
    alert("hi");
    alert(mobj.create("hello"));
});
```

Comment: See what I wrote at @mgraph's answer.

Comment: @agam360, then that has to do with another part of your code, and it's impossible to tell why unless you show the rest of your code (if you do that, please do it an another question). This is the answer to the question you posed.

Comment: When I used my code before, it works seamlessly with not requirement to change the object name.

Comment: @agam360, then you changed something else. This would simply never work, whether you have jquery or not.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the func var name :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var mfunc2 = new mfunc();
    alert("hi");
    alert(mfunc2.create("hello"));

 });
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TwKZu/

Comment: Now I get:missing : after property id & myfunc is not defined